# Where does the word mandate come from?

Tags: etymology

I am looking for historical information for the word mandate.

Comment: There is etymology online. But it is not always trustworthy. [Mandate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mandate)

Answer (score 1):

It is from classical Latin: OED etymology says:

> ***mandātum*** command, instruction, announcement, imperial
>   directive, use as noun of neuter of past participle of mandāre to hand
>   over, assign, command; compare -ate suffix1.Classical Latin mandāre 
>   is cognate with Oscan manafum  (1st singular preterite), amanaffed 
>   (3rd singular preterite) commanded, ordered: the first element is <
>   the base of manus  hand (see manus n.1); the second is probably the
>   same as the second element in abdere  to conceal (for which see
>   discussion s.v. do v.), although the reason for the change in
>   conjugation is unclear. Compare Middle French, French mandat  (late
>   15th cent.), and in various senses (e.g.  4b) also Old French, Middle
>   French, French mandement mandement n.  Compare earlier mandatary n.,
>   mandatory adj.

**There are multiple senses in which the noun and the verb are used. But they mostly involve the idea of a legal authority to act, granted by a king, a government, a court etc.**